# Spring Batch Chunk processing

Tags: java, spring-batch

When processing a step level using chunk processing(specifying a commit-interval) in Spring Batch,is there a way to know inside the Writer,when all the records in a file have been read and processed.My idea was to pass the collection of records read from the file to the ExecutionContext once all the records have been read.

Please help.

Comment: What do you want to do with the information that all data is read and processed (but not yet written?) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the is one of pre-built `CompletionPolicy` that do what you want, but if none you can write a custom [`CompletionPolicy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/repeat/CompletionPolicy.html) that mark a chunk as completed when writer return `null`; in this way you hold all items read from file.
After that, are you sure this is exactly what you wnat? because store all item in ExecutionContext is not a good pratice; also you will lose chunk processing, restartability, and all other SB features...

Comment: Thanks Luca for your response.My requirement is to to basically read a file(can contain millions of records).I have not explored the CompletionPolicy approach.Can this be specified for every Reader/Writer?Ultimately,I want all the files read from the file to be sent to the next step for Record level validation,transformation and then generating an output file.Thanks again.

Comment: the last bit - sending data to next step, might be better suited for a staging (database) table

Comment: Thanks Michael for your response.Do you mean that if all the records that are being read from the file need to be passed to the next step for validation/transformation etc,I should insert them into a Staging table and then have the next step do a read again from the table?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: why do you need to read all records in memory and then use an extra step to process/transform/read every record? this type of problem is a standard scenario in SB and can be resolved using single step with a `FlatFileItemReader`, an `ItemProcessor` and a `FlatFileItemWriter`

Comment: Thanks Luca.Yes,this appears to be a standard scenario.Before your most recent comment,I was too thinking about having everything in one step.But there could be a couple of different validation and transformation steps involved.Hence I was thinking of multiple steps.Besides using the executionContext is there a different way to exchange data between steps.Somewhere in the forum,there was a suggestion to use Spring beans.Thanks.