# Spring Batch Java Config commit interval

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-batch, spring-java-config

How do I configure Spring Batch (using Java Configuration) to write all chunks in a single transaction?

I have a simple simple Spring Batch Job with a single step. The step is made of a `JdbcCursorItemReader`, a custom item processor and a custom item writer. Currently I set the chunk size on the `StepBuilder`. This also seems to set the commit interval to the same value. On one hand I don't want to load all items into memory and therefore need chunk oriented processing. On the other hand the processor needs a single transaction over all the items not just the ones in the current chunk. It won't store the items in memory. It's ok if `#write` is called several times.

How can this be achieved using Java Configuration?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, this approach breaks the way spring-batch is designed.

The whole idea behind batch processing in spring is, that you commit every chunk and that spring-batch keeps track which records already have been processed, in order to provide restart, skip and failure handling strategies.

If you really need a transaction over the whole process, why using spring-batch at all? I mean, you could use the reader and writers directly and use them in your own simple loop. Something like this.

```
transaction.open();
while (not all processed) {
  List currentChunk = new List..;
  for(int i<0;i<chunkSize;i++) {
      Object readItem = jdbcCursorItemReader.read();
      if (readItem == null) {
         break;
      }
      Object processedItem = processor.process(readItem);
      if (processedItem != null) {
          currentChunk.add(processedItem);
      }
  }

  yourWriter.write(currentChunk);
}
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: I wonder if this could be done with a step execution listener.

Comment: I guess it could be. We would try to open the transaction in the beforeStep method and commit it in the afterStep method. What I'm not sure about: can we somehow configure the writer to use our own transaction? But then there is still the problem, that we circumvent core concepts of SB. Moreover, it would also only work for small workloads,, since we generally don't want to have a long running transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Write all chunks in one time is opposite to SB design and philosopy.
If you want you can read all item, put them in one big chunk and write; you will achive the same result.
Check [Spring Batch Chunk processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697779/spring-batch-chunk-processing/31698081#31698081) for a possible solution.

Comment: No, it will not be same result. All items will be in memory which is only possible for small workloads.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I don't know how to hack SB transaction management